# count occurrences of each value for each names across list or vector

Tags: r, list, vector, find-occurrences

I want to count occurrences of *each value* for each `names()` across a list (alt a vector)

```
lst <- list(`a,b`=1, `b,a`=2, `a,b`=2, `b,a`=1,`a,b`=1,`a,b`=2,`b,a`=1) # list
vec <- unlist(lst) # vector
# ether list or vector would work
```

I can't figure out to go about this. I've tried different alternatives using `table()`, `tabulation()`, `str_count()`, or e.g. `sapply(names(lst), function(x) sum(sapply(vec, function(y) all(y==x))))`

For the above dummy example, the desired output would look *something like*:

```
$`a,b`
1: 2
2: 2

$`b,a`
1: 2
2: 1
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try `table(vec, names(vec))`

Comment: Or, for your list: `lapply(split(lst, names(lst)), function(x) table(unlist(x)))`

Comment: @jbaums That looks like the answer the OP wants.  Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Ha, jeez, I'm embarrassed- definitely thought I tried `table(vec, names(vec))`. Big thanks for both solutions.